# How to disable main activity FAB into another fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, frontend

I have a scenario where I am using Bottom App bar in main activity which is also a navhostfragment and other fragments for various screens.

**Navhost Fragment (MainActivity)**

[image]

As its visible that a fab is displayed on recipe fragment. The issue is I only want this fab on recipe fragment and not on others. On others I just want the bottom app bar.

### How do I solve this without creating app bar for each fragment?

**mainactivity xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_appbar" />

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## I managed to show different fragments when item is clicked in bottom app bar but do not want to show fab on fragments other then recipe fragment.

### I am using Kotlin, so a solution in that would be helpful.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Okay! Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you can listen to destination changes from the `NavController` class by calling `addOnDestinationChangedListener` inside the activity were your navigation components reside, following is a sample code of hiding/showing **FAB** on different fragments being showed:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
        val bottomAppBar = findViewById<BottomAppBar>(R.id.bottomAppBar)


        // here is the part where you hide and show FAB
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->


            when ((destination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className) {
                // show fab in recipe fragment
                RecipeFragment::class.qualifiedName -> {

                    fab.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    // todo: set those values properly
                    bottomAppBar.fabCradleMargin = 30f
                    bottomAppBar.fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius = 30f
                    bottomAppBar.cradleVerticalOffset = 30f

                }
                // hide on other fragments
                else -> {
                    fab.visibility = View.GONE

                    bottomAppBar.fabCradleMargin = 0f
                    bottomAppBar.fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius = 0f
                    bottomAppBar.cradleVerticalOffset = 0f

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```